# How to include a page in a table by clicking a category in a menu (or in another table)?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have following two tables and a script having a function `includePage()`. Table with id=1 contains a menu whereas table with id2 is empty. It just contain one cell.

Now I want that when a user click on the first option in the menu of table having id=1, a dummypage1.html may appear in the table having id=2. Similarly when a click is on the second option of menu of table having id=1, a dummypage2.html may appear in the table having id=2.

**How exactly can I tell the browser with the help of script to include the pages in table having id=2?** Please help.

```
<table id="1">
 <tr>
    <td id="choice1" onclick="loadPage()">Initialize Session</td></tr>
    <td id="choice2" onclick="loadPage()">Sessions Information</td></tr>  
 </tr>
</table>
```

---

```
<table id="2">
    
</table>
```

---

```
<script language="javascript">
            
    function loadPage(){
        //if (document.getElementById('choice1')
        //      {
        //          <iframe src="sessionInformationTable.html" width="727px" height="416px"></iframe>
        //      }
    }
      
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a parameter on loadPage function

```
<td id="choice1" onclick="loadPage(1)">Initialize Session</td></tr>
<td id="choice2" onclick="loadPage(2)">Sessions Information</td></tr>  

<table id="2">
    <tr><td id="TD"></td></tr>
</table>
 <script>
   function loadPage(whatPage) {
        var url = (whatPage==1) ? "initSession.html" : "infoSession.html";
        document.getElementById('TD').innerHTML = '<iframe src="'+url+'" width="727px" height="416px"></iframe>';
   }
</script>
```

OR

```
<table id="2"><tr><td><iframe src="about:blank" id="content" style='width:100%;height:100%;"/></td></tr></table>
```

then on the javascript:

```
function loadPage(whatPage) {
   document.getElementById('content').src =  (whatPage==1) ? "initSession.html" :   "infoSession.html";
 }
```

Comment: Thank a lot for you help. That was perfect. :)

Tell me one more thing:

Suppose initSession.html has a table in it having many rows. What if i want that when a user clicks on a particular row of that table then some text box may appear under that table revealing some information related to that particular row.

Do i need to use ajax for it? Any suggestion...

Comment: If the information is not quite big and doesn't need to be the latest, you can attach that info into every row, then retrieve that data and display on the textbox below when the row is click.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about  following methodology

CLICK ON TABLE1 --> ROW1 --> displays --> Page1.html in TABLE-A
CLICK ON TABLE1 --> ROW2 --> displays --> Page2.html in table-B

this kind of designing leads to more tables when the age increases.

Better use this kind of style..

CLICK ON TABLE1 --> ROW1 --> displays --> Page1.html in TABLE-A
CLICK ON TABLE1 --> ROW2 --> displays --> Page2.html in TABLE-A

The thing is place an IFRAME inside the TABLE-A, and when clicking the ROW1 or ROW2 or ROW-n
set thet page target to that iframe.

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="http://www.google.com" target="myplace">Page1</a></td>
            <td>
                <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="myplace">Page2</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <iframe style="width: 400px; height: 400px;" id="myplace" name="myplace"></iframe>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to make a AJAX call to request the content, and place it in the table setting a innerHTML property.

For AJAX calls you can use a variety of libraries, I personally recommend jquery and dojotoolkit.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
<table id="1">
 <tr>
    <td id="choice1">Initialize Session</td></tr>
    <td id="choice2">Sessions Information</td></tr>  
 </tr>
```

```
<table id="2">
    <tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#choice1,#choice2").click(loadPage);
    });

    function loadPage(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        if(id === "choice1") {
            $("#2 td").load("initSession.html");
        } else if (id === "choice2") {
            $("#2 td").load("infoSession.html");
        }
    }
    </script>
```